# Netty: How to add websocket handshake and framing while still supporting native socket

Tags: websocket, netty

To me it looks like there is no out of the box support with mixed websocket/native socket for Netty 4.  I'm using custom binary protocol on my server and it is supposed to support both native and websocket on the same port. Here is what I'm trying in my `ServerInitializer`:

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {

    System.out.println("channel initialized");

    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
    pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));

    // client decoders cannot be singleton....
    pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketDecoder(), new ClientCommandDecoder());

    pipeline.addLast(this.webSocketEncoder, this.serverCommandEncoder);

    pipeline.addLast(this.roomHandler);
}
```

The `WebSocketDecoder` is taken from the examples, however it seems to use a handshaker which handles only `FullHttpRequest`s which makes use of `HttpObjectAggregator` mandatory.

However both `HttpServerCodec` and `HttpObjectAggregator` don't seem to pass the input data by if it is not HTTP requests. So here is what I wonder:

1. Can I write custom implementations of given classes and override logic in order to pass the input data if it is not web socket but native
2. Or can I somehow detect if input data is from websocket and swerve to two different flows (one with HTTP support, other without)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to adjust the pipeline on the fly depending on your input.

Please check our [PortUnification](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/portunification/PortUnificationServerHandler.java) example...

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll check it out. So does this mean there is no web socket encoder/decoder that pass the data to next handler if not http?